# Numpy array with arrays of different size inside

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a 3D `np.array` named `output` of varying size. An array of size (5,a,b); with a and b varying (b decreasing):

```
(a,b) = (1000,20)
(a,b) = (1000,19)
(a,b) = (1000,18)
(a,b) = (1000,17)
(a,b) = (1000,16)
```

I could create an array of arrays in order to do so, but later on I want to get the first column of all the arrays (without a loop) then I cannot use:

```
output[:,:,0]
```

Concatenating them wont work also, it asks for the same size of the arrays...

Any alternatives to be able to have a varying single array instead of an array of arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, create an array with object dtype and assign.

Comment: do you mean you want to create a np.array with varying shape (a,b)? the shape of np.array has to be defined during creation and is fixed

Comment: If you don't want a list or object array of size 5 (or maybe shape (5,10000), you'll need to make a (5,1000,20) array with some sort of padding for the shorter entries.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Divakar said, create an empty array with type object and assign the different sized arrays to their respective indices.

```
import numpy as np

arrs = [np.ones((5, i, 10 - i)) for i in range(10)]
arrs[0].shape
(5, 0, 10)
arrs[1].shape
(5, 1, 9)
out = np.emtpy(len(arrs), dtype=object)
out[:] = arrs
out[0].shape
(5, 0, 10)
out[1].shape
(5, 1, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks but as I explained in the edited question, an array of arrays complicates the whole problem...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could make a list and add this 5 arrays.